# Webpack 3 SVG load error

Tags: javascript, svg, webpack

Not sure why I'm getting this error as webpack is setup the same as an older project.

[image]

```
ERROR in ./app/static/imgs/sketch.svg
Module parse failed: /Users/leongaban/projects/personal/CoinHover/coinhover.io/app/static/imgs/sketch.svg Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
| <svg width="400px" height="400px" viewBox="0 0 400 400" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
|     <!-- Generator: Sketch 47 (45396) - http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch -->
 @ ./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./app/coinhover.scss 6:13780-13815
error Command failed with exit code 2.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

The _svg.scss file:

```
.close-x {
    position: relative;
    background-size: 400px 400px;
    background-image: url('static/imgs/sketch.svg'), none;
}

.close-x {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-position: -41px -2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "coinhover",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "Leon Gaban",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack && webpack-dev-server",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server",
    "build": "webpack -p",
    "production": "webpack -p",
    "test": "eslint app && jest",
    "test:fix": "eslint --fix app"
  },
  "now": {
    "name": "coinhover",
    "engines": {
      "node": "7.4.x"
    },
    "alias": "coinhover.io"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {},
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "jsx"
    ],
    "moduleDirectories": [
      "node_modules"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.16.2",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "chalk": "^2.1.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.10",
    "ramda": "^0.24.1",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.5",
    "react-router": "^4.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.2",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "svg-loader": "^0.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react-hmre": "^1.1.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.4",
    "enzyme": "^2.9.1",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^1.5.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.29.0",
    "jest": "^20.0.4",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "^15.6.1",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.2.3",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.9",
    "webpack": "^3.3.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.5.1"
  }
}
```

webpack

```
import webpack from 'webpack';
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';
import ExtractTextPlugin from 'extract-text-webpack-plugin';
import CopyWebpackPlugin from 'copy-webpack-plugin';
import path from 'path';
import chalk from 'chalk';

const coinhover = path.resolve(__dirname, 'coinhover');
const app = path.resolve(__dirname, 'app');
const log = console.log;
// https://gist.github.com/leongaban/dc92204454b3513e511645af98107775

const HtmlWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: `${__dirname}/app/index.html`,
  filename: 'index.html',
  inject: 'body'
});

const ExtractTextPluginConfig = new ExtractTextPlugin({
  filename: 'coinhover.css',
  disable: false,
  allChunks: true
});

const CopyWebpackPluginConfig = new CopyWebpackPlugin([{ from: 'app/static', to: 'static' }]);

const PATHS = {
  app,
  build: coinhover
};

const LAUNCH_COMMAND = process.env.npm_lifecycle_event;

const isProduction = LAUNCH_COMMAND === 'production';
process.env.BABEL_ENV = LAUNCH_COMMAND;

const productionPlugin = new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'process.env': {
    NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production')
  }
});

const base = {
  entry: [
    PATHS.app
  ],
  output: {
    path: PATHS.build,
    filename: 'index_bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['babel-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
          publicPath: coinhover
        })
      }
    ],
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader' },
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader' },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot)(\?.*$|$)/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000'
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: { modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'), 'node_modules'] }
  // resolve: {
  //   modules: ['node_modules', path.resolve(__dirname, '/app')]
  // }
};

const developmentConfig = {
  devServer: {
    publicPath: '',
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    quiet: true,
    inline: true,
    compress: true,
    stats: 'errors-only',
    open: true
  },
  devtool: 'cheap-module-inline-source-map',
  plugins: [
    CopyWebpackPluginConfig,
    ExtractTextPluginConfig,
    HtmlWebpackPluginConfig
  ]
};

const productionConfig = {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
  plugins: [
    CopyWebpackPluginConfig,
    ExtractTextPluginConfig,
    HtmlWebpackPluginConfig,
    productionPlugin
  ]
};

log(`${chalk.magenta(' ')} ${chalk.italic.green('npm run:')} ${chalk.red(LAUNCH_COMMAND)}`);

export default Object.assign({}, base,
  isProduction === true ? productionConfig : developmentConfig
);
```

Comment: [Do not post images of code or errors!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714)

Comment: The error obviously is at the start of file sketch.svg. Make sure the first character is a `<`, as required by XML. Most frequent errors are a space or a BOM erroneously not understood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know if its equivocal in the version of Webpack you are using (I've been using 1.15.0), but Webpack has issues parsing certain `<xml>` tags and within the `<svg>` element there are sometimes `xmls/xmlns` attributes that Webpack has problems parsing. These are generally erroneous verbose leftovers from Illustrator or other SVG generating applications. I had a very similar if not identical error where Webpack prompted for a loader in the error screen.

I bet if you strip your "sketch.svg" document of the `<xml>` tag wrapper and possibly the `xmlns` attributes *as well* Webpack will compile successfully.

(Boo to the users who gripe about stackoverflow best practices and do not even attempt to help.)